# calculate start and end angle of piechart slice

Tags: apache-flex

In Flex 3 how to calculate start and end angle(point) of every pie chart slices?

Thanks,
aravindakumarThangaraju

Comment: I think taht your question is too vague. Could explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: i need to calculate the start and end point of the every slice in the pie chart.please go through the below link
http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/6315/piechartj.png
Thanks,
aravindakumarThangaraju.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pie chart has 360 degrees, so if you take the percentage that each slice represents and multiply that by 360 you'll get the angle in degrees.

Pick any one of the edges as your zero axis and add relative to that.